# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'string'

Tags: python

python code screenshot capture

**what is the matter? about it?**

```
html = """ <html><body>(html)(body)  
<h1>(h1)what is the scraping(/h1)</h1>
<p>(p)To analyze a web page(/p)</p> 
<p>(p)To extract the desired part(/p)</p>
(/body)(/html)</body></html> """

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser') 

title = soup.find(id="title")

body = soup.find(id="body")

print ("title=" + title.string)

print ("body=" + body.string)
```

Comment: You need to properly format the code and give us a question to answer.

Comment: Both your `soup.find` calls are returning None. Next time, you need to include the full traceback of your error. Furthermore, explain what your code is supposed to do and what you expect.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: Attribute Error - 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'something'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8949252/python-attribute-error-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-something)

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to find an element with id equals to `title`, something like `<p id="title">foo bar</p>`.

If you want to find tag by its type, do:

```
soup.find('body') # returns content of <body>
```

Or

```
soup.find('title')
```

*The second example will not works in your case because there is no `<title>foo bar</title>` tag in your html, but you got the idea.*

Answer (score 0):

There is no `title` tag in your `html`. So, `title=None`. Hence you can't get any content out of it.

Try it with lxml instead of html.parser and try soup.body instead of searching for body tag.

Comment: `soup.find(id="body")` is also returning `None`.

Comment: Try soup.body instead of find(body) and also try with lxml instead of html.parser

Comment: I'm not the question asker. I'm stating that there is another mistake in the code so you can add it to your answer. Make your answer more complete.